# Docker Compose service is making request to another service with IP

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a development server where I am using Docker Compose to run all the related services. The docker-compose file looks roughly like:

```yaml
services:
  webserver:
    - ports:
      - "${HOST_PORT}:${CONTAINER_PORT}"
  redis:
    - ports:
      - "${REDIS_PORT}:${REDIS_PORT}"
  apiserver:
    - ports:
      - "8383:8383"
```

(not a complete compose file, but I've only included what I believe are the relevant bits)

`webserver` spins up a BullMQ queue, which talks to `redis`. In one of the jobs that I have configured, I make a request to `apiserver`, via `http://apiserver:8383/endpoint`. If I ssh into the redis container and view the job that gets queue, I see that it has failed with the following: `connect ECONNREFUSED 172.25.0.3:8383`.

This works just fine when I run docker compose locally. Any idea why this might not be working?

Update:
Attempting a `wget` from within the web server instance:

`wget http://apiserver:8383`

results in:

```
wget http://apiserver:8383
--2022-12-24 23:58:28--  http://apiserver:8383/
Resolving apiserver (apiserver)... 172.26.0.4
Connecting to apiserver (apiserver)|172.26.0.4|:8383... failed: Connection refused.
```

Comment: Can you ping/ telnet from webserver to api_server? Try docker exec into webserver and check connectivity with system tools... just to eliminate your application from being the issue

Comment: Also please check docker versions and docker-compose versions across machines

Comment: Updated with the results of that attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the responses. It turns out I wasn't paying close enough attention to the startup messages, and the `apiserver` was being `Killed` by Docker due to using too much memory. So the connection was refused because the server wasn't actually running.

Answer (score 0):

Docker-compose service names have to respect domain name standard format.
Underscore "_" is not allowed in domain names.
Raname your service to api**-**server instead, you'll be good

Comment: Sorry, my post is misleading, that's not actually what it is called. I just used that as an example placeholder. The actual value is a single word, no underscores. Post updated to be more clear.

Comment: I didn't pay attention to the snippet from your docker-compose too.
A service is actually a Map not a List, so delete the "-" before Ports:
Try "docker inspect apiserver"  and see if it exposes any ports before and after